# Symbol for Gaussian distribution

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations

What is the symbol for the normal density function in LaTeX?

Comment: Can you link to a picture of the symbol you're looking for? It's not clear from the question what it is you want...

Comment: When I went to look it up I realised that it is \mathcal{N}. Sorry.

Comment: @asdf123: It would be nice if you just note the solution you found below as an answer and mark it as "accepted". This way everybody can see that the question is answered resp. closed and not open any more.

Comment: For such things it's always worth to take a look at »Wikipedia«.

Comment: @asdfl123 @Thorsten ... and if you look under the edit tag in the Wikipedia you will see the actual LaTeX command!

Comment: FWIW, LaTeX doesn't attach any particular meaning to symbols, so asking what symbol is used for a particular function is not a question about LaTeX, it's a question about math. Only once you know what the symbol _looks_ like does it become a LaTeX question ("how do I create this glyph in LaTeX").

Comment: @DavidZ This might not be the intended use of this SE but FWIW I find it incredibly useful to search this site for a math symbol I want to know the meaning of, I got here by googling "curly N in equation latex" and thanks to this page I found out that represented a normal distribution. If I take the "latex" out of the search the results are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 149):

asdf123 wrote:

```
...I realised that it is \mathcal{N}.
```

Answer (score 53):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution):

[image: X ~ N(mu, sigma^2)]

where code for the displayed equation is:

```
\[
  X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})\,.
\]
```

Comment: What i really wanted was \sigma^2, not mathcal{N}, so thanks for writing the full form.

Answer (score 3):

```
X \hookrightarrow  \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})
```

this one is better I think :p

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you explain a bit, why? Always helpful:[How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It's the most used in books

Comment: `\mathcal{N}` is standardly used for the normal distribution and is arguably more correct than just `N`, but I have not seen a single instance of `\hookrightarrow` being used for "distributed as". Have you?

Answer (score 3):

In this [website](https://mathvault.ca/hub/higher-math/math-symbols/probability-statistics-symbols/) or on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) there are a large common of list of probability and statistics-symbols:

[image]

For Wikipedia click in edit and you can see the used code.

Comment: At this time, February 2022, the wikipedia page you link to appears to use `\mathcal{N}`, which looks different from the upright font you used in your table.

Comment: @PatrickT I have seen again the page of my link but I not see the \mathcal{N}. Where you have seen this apparence? I see the classic $N$. Bye.

Comment: Here's what I see on wikipedia as of Feb 16, 2022 (copy-pasted from the source code under "Notation"): `https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/863304aaa42a945f2f07d79facc3d2eebc845ce7` It's `\mathcal`. That's what I mean by my comment above.

Comment: And by the way, I prefer upright, I'm not a big fan of `\mathcal`!

Comment: @PatrickT Ah but it not is wikipedia but in wikimedia :-). I prefer $N$ and not \mathcal.

Comment: wikimedia is where wikipedia stores things like images. The `\mathcal` comes from the wikipedia page you cite, it's in several places, including where it has the **Notation** in the column on the rhs.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me. For that I used dollar sign before and after that and it did work like this;

\STATEx $\mathcal{N}$(\mu, $\sigma^2 $))$

This worked for me. I hope it may help others as well.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Surely we can give you an answer: but this answer must be possibly where needed followed by a small compilable latex code where we can see your work. Please can you post a MinimalWorkingExample? What is \STATEx? How your code work?