# Gaussian "G" font?

Tags: math-fonts

[image]

Any ideas on how to include a single letter "G" to look like this one into my paper? What kind of font would it be? I am including it in my paragraphs and math-mode.

Comment: `$\mathcal{G}$`

Comment: Tangentially related: [Symbol for Gaussian distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6969/5764)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that little trick!!