# How to type a math symbol N

Tags: math-mode

How can I get a big N like the one below?

[image]

Comment: `\mathcall{N}` .

Comment: Yea, `\mathcal{N}` works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textmath, active,tightpage]{preview} % don't use in real document
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{N}(x|\mu,\sigma^2)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

(also see [symbol for Gaussian distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/symbol-for-gaussian-distribution/347558#347558))